# Mutable variable is accessible from closure. What's causing this and how can I solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing an ajax call and in the done block I'm appending a value to an object I created outside of the ajax block, but I get the warning when I run this: "Mutable variable is accessible from closure." What does it mean and what am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
var some_object = { // This is the variable that's "mutable"
    rooms: 4,
    area: 45
};

$.ajax({

}).done(function (data) {
    some_object.value = 10; // The warning appears here, on some_object
});
```

Comment: It's coming from your IDE.

Comment: The warning might be justified [in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572), though.